# unicode assignment failing in NSString?

Tags: objective-c, unicode

The following fails for both unichar assignments?

```
unsigned int c = 0x0001d122;
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\U%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08X", c]];
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\U%08X", c];
```

---

I am trying to do this programmatically (adding in the "\U" makes things difficult as seen above):

```
nssSymbol = @"\U0001d122"; \\this works... but need to be able to vary 'c'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handling of the `\Unnnnnnnn` construct in a string literal is done at compile time. You can't build the construct at run time and have it interpreted. That's not how things work.

You could do:

```
uint32_t c = 0x0001d122;
NSString* s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&c length:sizeof(c) encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
```

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", s);  returns (null), where s = @"\U0001d122"; and then do NSLog(@"%@", s);  return the symbol

Comment: This answer will work if you change the encoding to `NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding`.

Comment: Thx rmaddy... the endian change did it.

Answer (score 2):

As shown by Ken Thomases answer you can create a string from bytes, however you must know the endianness of your machine or use the endian conversion routines.

For example, on an Intel Mac which is little endian you can use:

```
uint32_t c = 0x0001d122;
NSString* s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&c
                                       length:sizeof(c)
                                     encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
```

If you don't wish to code in knowledge of the systems endianness you can use the conversion routines. For example:

```
uint32_t c = EndianU32_NtoB(0x0001d122); // convert from native endianness to big endian
NSString* s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&c
                                       length:sizeof(c)
                                     encoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
```

HTH

Comment: since Ken answered the bulk, I gave him the check... but you put out the machine type for choosing endian so I gave you a point as well.